# Can't write to file anywhere except OnCreate() in Android 7.1.1

Tags: java, android, file

I am unable to create or write to files anywhere except in the OnCreate() method. If I try call a function I've written to create files when I press a button, it does not do it but it runs my code. Same for writing to files, it will not do so. Is there something I am not understanding in Android that is stopping it from writing files outside of OnCreate()? If I make the buttons do other functions they work but only creating/writing files does not work except in OnCreate().

As requested I added the code below.

OnCreate function:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    folderTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);

    if (checkPermissions()){
    }

    Button bAccelerometer = (Button) findViewById((R.id.Accelerometer));
    Button bCamera = (Button) findViewById((R.id.Camera));

    xATV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    yATV = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.textView2));
    zATV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    xFTV = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.textView4));

    if (isExternalStorageWritable()){
        xATV.setText("Writeable");
    }
    if(isExternalStorageReadable()){
        yATV.setText("Readable");
    }
    //createFiles(); this code works only in this method
   // writeToFile("x_filtered.txt");


    sManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sAccelerometer = sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);
}
```

OnSensorChanged() function where I want to write to file

```
    @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
    //sManager.unregisterListener((SensorEventListener) this, sAccelerometer);

    tEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long tDelta = tEnd - tStart;
    if (tDelta >= 100.0) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION) {

            double x = Math.round(event.values[0] * 100.0) / 100.0;
            double y = Math.round(event.values[1] * 100.0) / 100.0;
            double z = Math.round(event.values[2] * 100.0) / 100.0;

            //zero accelerometer data
            if (x <= 0.08 && x >= -0.08) {
                x = 0.0;
            }
            if (y <= 0.08 && y >= -0.08) {
                y = 0.0;
            }
            if (z <= 0.08 && z >= -0.08) {
                z = 0.0;
            }
             if (writeToFile == true){
                 writeToFile("x_unfiltered.txt"); //this code will run but 
                 writeToFile = false;             //but when observed, file still empty
             }
            xAcc_unfiltered[i] = x;
            yAcc_unfiltered[i] = y;
            zAcc_unfiltered[i] = z;
            i++;
            if (i == 10) {

                xAcc_filtered = medianFilter(xAcc_unfiltered);

                i = 0;

            }
        }
        tStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

    }
}
```

Right now I am only writing dummy data in writeToFile() and here is the code for that function:

```
     public void writeToFile(String fname){
    File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + "/project_docs", fname);
    if (myFile.exists()){
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.write("test");
            for (int m = 0; m < 10; m++){
                myOutWriter.append("test");
            }
            folderTV.setText("Finish writing");

            myOutWriter.flush();

            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
    else{
        folderTV.setText("File not exist, make sure using the right path!");
    }
}

    public void createFiles() {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/project_docs");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    String fname = "x_filtered.txt";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });
    fname = "y_filtered.txt";
    file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });
    fname = "z_filtered.txt";
    file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });
    fname = "z_unfiltered.txt";
    file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });
    fname = "y_unfiltered.txt";
    file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });
    // Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
    // immediately available to the user.
    fname = "x_unfiltered.txt";
    file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: can you post the code which is not wiorking so people can understand the issue ?

Comment: "Is there something I am not understanding in Android that is stopping it from writing files outside of OnCreate()?" -- there is no such limitation. For example, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Files/FilesEditor) performs file I/O outside of `onCreate()`. In fact, doing I/O *inside* of `onCreate()` is bad, as you freeze your UI while waiting for the I/O to complete.

Comment: @AalapPatel I added my code.

Comment: @CommonsWare do you have any idea how I can store sensor data in files or can show me how? I am really struggling with this seemingly simple task. I added my code showing my directories and how I try to store data but it does not store data at all :(. Right now I am trying to do it in onSensorChanged() but that doesn't work.

Comment: "Right now I am trying to do it in onSensorChanged() but that doesn't work" -- that will be called far too often. Buffer your results and write them out periodically.

Comment: @CommonsWare I only gather data every 10 times a second (in OnSensorChanged() as you can see I only capture data if tDelta > 100 milliseconds). Surely this is slow enough for the file writing?

Comment: I would not assume that disk I/O will take < 100ms. Moreover, continuously writing to disk is hard on the device (battery, etc.). Buffer your results and write them out periodically.

Comment: @CommonsWare I re-coded it such that I have two buttons now. First button starts the sensor and gathers 100 readings. After 100 readings, send message to a TextView that 100 readings have been taken and to stop listening to sensor. 
Second button then stores the data (the arrays of size 100 are global and populated in the OnSensorChanged() method). 

It does not write to file and I have no idea why. Still same code as above. I even output to textview after each write. It simply will not append anything to created files. I am honestly at a loss.

Comment: In `createFiles()`, you are working in a `/project_docs` subdirectory, whereas in `writeFile()`, you are not. `createFiles()` itself seems to be pointless, as the files will be created when you write to them for real, and you should only index them via `MediaScannerConnection` when you are completely done writing to the file. You are also catching exceptions without logging them, so if you are crashing, you will never know.